# Large Media Library

Tags: gallery, media, media-library

I'm looking to organize a large WordPress Movies/Actors site, with thousands of posters, screenshots, etc...  I currently have the images in a directory structure like /actors/firstname_lastname/filename1, etc.. with a database matching each pathname with a movie.  Some names may have thousands of images.  I suppose I want to import these into WP media library, and start using them in WP.  I don't know whether to attach them to a post, one post per name, or if there's a better approach.  How would you solve this problem?

Comment: I would not use WordPress for this, let's just say it's media management capabilities leave a lot to be desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not do it post by post I would use a  plugin so I can manage it more and present them in lightbox or as a gallery.  Plus in the future if you want to blog or add news you can always use the posts for that.

Nextgen Gallery has been around for some years and I manage tons of photos and I can export and import pics with no hassle.

The built in wordpress gallery as an option sucks in my opinion.

You should maybe get pixelmine plugin (cost some) if you want to steer away from the gallery look and have albums and such.